# How to disable the volume popup in KDE Plasma 5.13?

Tags: kde, plasma5, kde5, audio-volume

In older versions I used to comment out `osd.show(percent)` in the functions `increaseVolume` and `decreaseVolume` in the file `/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.volume/contents/ui/main.qml` ([blog source](https://sergiorafael.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/disable-kdeplasma-volume-osdpopup/)). But that file does not exist anymore in Plasma 5.13. Is there an other way to disable it?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if useful, but I modify the OSD to make it smaller and persist for less time. I patch the files in `/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/osd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the volume icon in the tray

[image]

and select `Configure KMix…`.

[image]

Unselect `Show On Screen Display (OSD)` then click `OK` (or `Apply`).

This is equivalent to editing `~/.config/kmixrc` and adding the line:

```
showOSD=false
```

Comment: P.S. I have no idea why my fonts, etc., are cropped like that.

Comment: When I right-click the volume icon I don't have the `Configure KMix` option. The only option I have is `Configure Audio Volume...`.

Comment: @MatMis I added a screenshot for when right-click the icon. What version of plasma are you on now? I'm using 5.15.4. I also wonder if your volume icon is not actually kmix, but something else.

Comment: @Sparkhawk I'm also using KDE 5.15.4 (on Antergos).

Comment: @Sparkhawk My screenshot [here](https://i.imgur.com/UFL8rWU.png)

Comment: Aha, [this issue](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201805) with two volume icons in the tray was what I was thinking of. The one that you are using is `Audio Volume`. If you right-click on the tray arrow, click `Configure System Tray…`, you can see it in the `General` tab. The "proper" one is in the `Entries` tab, and called `Volume Control`. I don't think you can totally hide it, so it might be in the tray arrow overflow?

Comment: It's not in [here](https://i.imgur.com/UWjwYFB.png) and not in [here](https://i.imgur.com/4Ccx0At.png)

Comment: Hmm… I'm not sure, but is `kmix` actually running? Try `ps aux | grep '[k]mix'`? If not, then try `$ kmix`?

Comment: Yes, kmix is not running, so it is not possible to configure it from tray. I have the same issue.

Comment: I have `kde-apps/kmix` not installed.

Comment: For me in `Plasma 5.21.2` it was `Configure Audio Volume...` and then `Show visual feedback for changes to:`. Then uncheck `Audio volume` and `Mute state`

Answer (score 1):

what you gotta do is right click the speakers tray icon and then click audio volume after that uncheck audio feedback and you're good to go

Comment: Please add the kde-plasma version for which your trick can apply. (It was not possible on the version the OP was running… 4 years ago…)